# iOS Swift 5 Custom View (non-storyboards): how to create an update view - so that the view loads with the current value in the TextField

Tags: ios, swift, forms, textfield

I am able to build a view with Swift 5 that will write data into my database.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to build the "update" view.

My goal is to take all of the current values in the database and have them display inside of the TextField object.  That way, the user starts with the current value in the field.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to pre-wire the data into the TexField object when the view loads.  Can someone please provide me with an example or a tutorial of how to accomplish this?

Here is my current code:

```
struct TripCreateModifyView: View {    
    @State private var pageTripName: String = ""
    
    init(tripName: String)
    {
        self.pageTripName = tripName
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack { Text(" Trip Name:"); TextField("Enter Trip Name", text: $pageTripName) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? 
You have a custom UIView, with a UITextfield. You want to set the initial value of the UITextfield? 
what's preventing you from doing UITextfield.text = ""?

Comment: @shayegh I have added a code snippet above that will hopefully help clarify.  Thanks for the quick initial response!